# Alternative way to start mysql server other than upstart?

Tags: mysql, upstart, init.d

I have a chrooted 10.04 LTS installation on a NAS, it works great but breaks Upstart very badly. MySQL only works via Upstart these days, so I created a workaround to start like this:

```
dtach -n /opt/svc/screens/mysql.dtach /usr/sbin/mysqld
```

However, I consider this very evil. Is there a better way to start MySQL server *other than* Upstart?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Newer releases of Upstart (included with Ubuntu 11.04 and later) include chroot support, though you will have to be on a chroot that is running on top of one of those releases.

If you can't do that, you could simply copy the init script from the Debian package. Its available here:

http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~ubuntu-branches/debian/sid/mysql-5.1/sid/view/head:/debian/mysql-server-5.1.mysql.init

You would put that in /etc/init.d as 'mysql', and run `chmod +x /etc/init.d/mysql` and then `update-rc.d mysql` to turn it on.